# Adding consistent raised pattern to surface of mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I'm fairly adapt when it comes to modeling, I'm currently working on Captain America's helmet from AOU. Attached is a work in progress, this was rendered in Keyshot... well you see the black areas with the texture, that was just for the the sake of nice renders. However those areas eventually need to have a consistent dot/bump pattern all over them, extruded subtly off the surface of the mesh. I've attached a photo of what I'm after for that. What is the easiest way to go about this? I need the pattern to follow the contours of the helmet, but also not get distorted, the nubs/balls needs to stay consistent size and spacing. I've tried using the shrinkwrap feature, but that's not cutting it. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

[image: My current mesh with faux "texture" done in rendering program]

[image: Texture Example]